# How to Reschedule Biometrics appointment for green card?

Tags: usa, greencard

While I am still traveling in Europe I received I797 notice to appear for fingerprint appointment the next business day after the upcoming weekend. The letter says, if I don't show up, then my green card case will be considered abandoned.

**What are my options to reschedule biometrics appointment (mail, phone, online)?**

Initially my immigration attorney told me to reschedule appointment over phone. Unfortunately, I tried to call USCIS at +1(800)375-5283 and they told me that they can't reschedule these appointments over phone, because "Alexandria office schedules them and they don't have any control".

Now, I am trying to understand - if I can ask a friend to send rescheduling request over mail "the proper way" by sending back the i797 form. However, it is already Friday and appointment is on Monday. **If my friend sends it out will USCIS honor the send date even if they may receive letter later after the original appointment time?**

*P.S. #1 I am solving this case with my immigration attorney in the meantime, but it seems that rescheduling appointments is a corner case that at least my employer's immigration attorneys is not very aware of. So I would like to hear outside opinion.*

*P.S. #2 In the worst case I am considering to buy ticket tomorrow back  to the US, but that would be hassle I would like to avoid.*

Comment: Did you request and receive advance parole before leaving the US?

Comment: @Dorothy Advance Parole was requested, but not yet received. My immigration attorney told me that I can still travel on my H1B visa after receiving i-485 receipt notices.

Comment: Then the advice, from a total stranger on the Internet, is to get on a plane and show up for that appointment on Monday.

Comment: @Dorothy Can you, please, explain why Advance Parole would make a difference for this situation? My immigration attorney was confident that there is no need to have it since I have valid H1B. Anyway, I would be more than happy to hear your opinion either way.

Comment: @Dorothy H visas are apparently one of a few exceptions to the normal rules regarding advance parole: http://www.immihelp.com/advance-parole/

Comment: @phoog would not the concern be that AP was applied for, and not _yet_ received? Truly, I'd be far more worried about saying I'm not available as I'm out of the country (and perhaps USCIS already knows that).

Answer (score 2):

I remember receiving my letter and it had the exact instructions on how to reschedule your appointment if you cannot make it. So you need to just get a copy of your letter to check for those instructions. Infact that is the exact response that the USCIS website has as well.

> https://my.uscis.gov/helpcenter/article/what-happens-if-i-can-t-attend-my-scheduled-biometrics-appointment

Just refer to that letter and follow those instructions accordingly.

Edit:
The above link is no longer available. [Here](https://web.archive.org/web/20180221172050/https://my.uscis.gov/helpcenter/article/what-happens-if-i-can-t-attend-my-scheduled-biometrics-appointment) is an archive, but note it may no longer be relevant.